# Reject emails from specific address on exim

Tags: spam, exim

i have a spammer that is driving me crazy.
What i want to do is reject his emails altogether so he receives an instant message saying "message rejected" or similar.

Can exim do this? How?

Note: This is an external gmail account sending emails to my personal server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the ACL.

Find the part of config starting with the line like that:

```
acl_rcpt:
```

Your config can be different but `acl`, `rcpt` and semicolon should be present. Then there should be a number of blocks, starting with `accept`, `deny`, `require` and other verbs.

You have to add the new block:

```
deny condition = ${lookup{$sender_address}nwildlsearch{/path/black.list}{yes}}
  message = Not that time, sorry.
```

File `/path/black.list` should contain banned addresses and/or regular expressions, one per line:

```
some_spammer@spammer\.tld
.*@bad\.domain\.tld
.*@.*\.badguys\..*
```

Sure you have to be familiar with REs, but you also can simply explicitly list unwanted senders.

Restart `exim` after reconfiguration.

P.S.
Keep in mind that `exim` proceed ACLs in order they are defined in the config. So final result can be a bit unexpected. Read carefully already present ACLs and try to understand their behaviour.